# How to present Google Drive file picker ios

Tags: ios, google-drive-api, dropbox

My application has an ability to download files from different services into documents directory. User can easily chose file from Dropbox using **Dropbox Chooser** drop-in. But i can't find how to present similar file picker in **Google Drive SDK**. How can i do this, or i need to create Google Drive file system presentation by myself ?

Comment: hi , I need to implement the same , do you find any way for Google Drive Sdk picker ?

Comment: thanks, even I didnt find it so I have used the sample Project by google SDK

Comment: have a look at this article https://kunalgupta1508.medium.com/integrating-google-drive-with-your-ios-app-e05c6ecc877e

Answer (score -1):

https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/

The example code works fine in safari ... I am having some issues with the pop up window for Oauth2 in current chrome.